# How to remove space between ul and wrapping element with border on a mobile device?

Tags: css, mobile, border, space

I have setup a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BaWC8/2/

You can see that I have a wrapper div containing an ul with li's. The li's have a with of 25% so they get evenly spread across the 'page'. The wrapping div has a border of 1px. Since all li's also have a border of 1px, it looks like they all have a border of 2px (which I want).

Now. This looks all good on a desktop but when you **open it on a mobile device** (iphone, android) you see a small spacing on the right side of the wrapper between the last li and the wrapper border.

Here is the code (html):

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>aaaa</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>bbbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>cccc</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>dddd</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Css:

```
body{
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
}
.wrap {
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
} 

.wrap ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
        width: 100%;
}

.wrap ul li {
    display: list-item;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 25%;
}

.wrap ul li a {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.wrap il li a span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

I do not understand why so I hope someone here can help me out.

Comment: Add a `padding: 0` to `.wrap`? A question, why do you have a `span` inside your `a`?? I don't think you need it...

Comment: Nope. No luck: http://jsfiddle.net/BaWC8/3 span is just example. In reality I have an image in there.

Comment: I can't test here, but what if you try removing all the whitespace at the end? That is, end with `</a></li></ul></div>` with no returns in between.

Comment: No, this does not solve it either: see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BaWC8/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the float and width from the .wrap and ul.

The border will on .wrap will collapse, which you can either solve with a clearfix, or by adding overflow:auto.

Here is my working CSS:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
}
.wrap {
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  overflow:auto;
} 
.wrap ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.wrap ul li {
  display: list-item;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 25%;
}
.wrap ul li a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.wrap il li a span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

A working fiddle, at least on iOS: http://jsfiddle.net/designingsean/BaWC8/7/

Comment: Well, that's more like it! Don't seem to understand why only mobile devices show the issue though...

Comment: I would imagine it has to do with how they interpret width:100%, if I had to guess.

Answer (score 1):

You see a small spacing because .wrap width is 100%+2px(border-width*2).

If you want border (or padding) don't expand element's width/height, 
you may use box-sizing: border-box; http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

add this css-property to .wrap and you will not see "small spacing" anymore))